# Multiple colors per letter in TextBlock with no spacing

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I would like to change the color of each letter in a word. However when I use

```
<TextBlock>
   <Run Foreground="Red" Text="F"/>
   <Run Foreground="Yellow" Text="o"/>
   <Run Foreground="Lime" Text="o"/>
   <Run Foreground="Magenta" Text="b"/>
   <Run Foreground="Blue" Text="a"/>
   <Run Foreground="Red" Text="r"/>
<TextBlock>

<TextBlock>
   <Span Foreground="Red">F</Span>
   <Span Foreground="Yellow">o</Span>
   <Span Foreground="Lime">o</Span>
   <Span Foreground="Magenta">b</Span>
   <Span Foreground="Blue">a</Span>
   <Span Foreground="Red">r</Span>
</TextBlock>
```

It contains spacings between the letters when running the app, not in the editor of Visual Studio 2012. I tried setting the fontStretch but it seems useless in this case. Can someone tell me how to color each letter separately without getting the spacing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is doing a space because of the style on SPAN block. It is display: inline-block.

If you want to remove it, you can do this:

```
<TextBlock>
   <Span Foreground="Red">F</Span
   ><Span Foreground="Yellow">o</Span
   ><Span Foreground="Lime">o</Span
   ><Span Foreground="Magenta">b</Span
   ><Span Foreground="Blue">a</Span
   ><Span Foreground="Red">r</Span>
</TextBlock>
```

It is just a little trick ;-)

Hope this helped !

EDIT: I think you can do a negative margin too :)

EDIT2: please, don't edit my code when you're doing something false, thanks ! (the >< span is the trick)